# Line graph scaling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to draw a d3 line graph, but the line ends up being a very small dot.

I have tried lots of different appriches to scaling, but none of the seem to work for me!!

If you run the snippet you see the blob, I have scaled it up (x60) so that is is visible, but it is clearly wrong.

```js
function addLineGraph(data) {

var size = { width: 1100, height: 700, padding: 80 }
        var g = d3.select(document.getElementById('chart'))
                     .append('svg')
                     .attr('width',size.width+size.padding)
                     .attr('height',size.height+size.padding)
                     .append('g').attr('transform','translate('+[size.padding,size.padding]+')')
        
        var x = d3.scaleLinear([0,size.width]).domain(d3.extent(data,d => d.booked))
        var y = d3.scaleLinear([size.height,0]).domain([23,156])

        var line = d3.line()
                        .x(d => x(d.booked))
                        .y(d => y(d.c_seat));
                        
            g.append('path').datum(data).attr('stroke-width','1').attr('stroke','red').style('transform','scale(60)').attr('d',line);
} 

addLineGraph([
  {
    "booked": 0,
    "c_seat": 23
  },
  {
    "booked": 143000,
    "c_seat": 34.5
  },
  {
    "booked": 17747436,
    "c_seat": 34.5
  },
  {
    "booked": 25724206,
    "c_seat": 60
  },
  {
    "booked": 346513093,
    "c_seat": 75
  },
  {
    "booked": 347831593,
    "c_seat": 91.75
  },
  {
    "booked": 432490753,
    "c_seat": 98.75
  },
  {
    "booked": 508046733,
    "c_seat": 98.75
  },
  {
    "booked": 524946916,
    "c_seat": 112.75
  },
  {
    "booked": 968110526,
    "c_seat": 156.25
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a D3 linear scale, you cannot set the range like this:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear([0,size.width])
    //don't put the range here--^
    .domain(d3.extent(data,d => d.booked))
```

You have to use `range` explicitly:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, size.width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.booked))
```

If you don't, the range will be set to the default value, which is [0, 1]. That's why your path is so small.

I believe that this mistake occurred because you can set the range in an *ordinal scale* the way you did:

```
d3.scaleOrdinal([range])
//range here-------^
```

Thus, in an ordinal scale (but not in a linear scale), this:

```
d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range([foo])
    .domain([bar])
```

Is the same of:

```
d3.scaleOrdinal([foo])
    .domain([bar])
```

Here is your modified code:

```js
function addLineGraph(data) {

  var size = {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    padding: 80
  }
  var g = d3.select("body")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', size.width + size.padding)
    .attr('height', size.height + size.padding)
    .append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + [size.padding, size.padding] + ')')

  var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, size.width]).domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.booked))
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([size.height, 0]).domain([23, 156])


  var line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.booked))
    .y(d => y(d.c_seat));

  g.append('path').datum(data).attr('stroke-width', '1').attr('stroke', 'red').attr('d', line);
}

addLineGraph([{
  "booked": 0,
  "c_seat": 23
}, {
  "booked": 143000,
  "c_seat": 34.5
}, {
  "booked": 17747436,
  "c_seat": 34.5
}, {
  "booked": 25724206,
  "c_seat": 60
}, {
  "booked": 346513093,
  "c_seat": 75
}, {
  "booked": 347831593,
  "c_seat": 91.75
}, {
  "booked": 432490753,
  "c_seat": 98.75
}, {
  "booked": 508046733,
  "c_seat": 98.75
}, {
  "booked": 524946916,
  "c_seat": 112.75
}, {
  "booked": 968110526,
  "c_seat": 156.25
}])
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```